# image map circle will only allow clicking on top line and bottom line of image

Tags: html, css

my image map wont allow clicking on the circle only the top and bottom line of the image

i tried resizing and i have checked many places and i cant see my error

```
<img src="../images/pumpkin.gif" alt="pumpkin" height="75" 
usemap="#pumpkin">
<map name="pumpkin">
    <area target="_self" alt="pumpkin" title="home" href="../index.html" 
coords="40,40,40" shape="circle">
</map>
```

i expect the image to be clickable anywhere in the 40 radius

Comment: Your code is working for me. I'm able to click on a 40 radius circle range.

Comment: thats why its annoying the code is correct but when i live preview on brakets it doesnt work and ive tried chrome and ie

Comment: Maybe you can try to reproduce your error in https://codepen.io/ and then post here so we can try to help

Comment: https://codepen.io/bmtmonkey/pen/bXpbXw

Comment: error is still there but this is the code the image doesnt appear cause it is local but ya the bottom of the pumpkin  in the heder is the only spot the link appears and it needs to cover the whole area